# HOW TO Update where in firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database with autogenerated primary keys.
Look here:

```
data 
------0
-----------id
-----------name
------1
-----------id
-----------name
```

and so on.

I don't know primary keys and I wanna update name by specific id. How can I do that?

Comment: If your items have their own ID, why aren't you storing them under that ID? With such a structure, your updates would be as simple as `ref.child(id).setValue(...)`.

Comment: I just took a json file and uploaded it to firebase. And then firebase added  own ids for my data

Comment: I recommend doing more than uploading a JSON file when it comes to data modeling. For example, you could do worse than reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and viewing [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s),

Comment: Thank you, Frank. You are rigth that it wasn't the best approach just to upload data from json. But it was just an experiment for this application and I don't know really whether or not I will use firebase database. And I just didn't want to spend a lot of time for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for that first create a class

```
public class User {

int id;
String name;

public User(int id, String name){
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Then get the db object you want to update

```
DatabaseReference dbRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("YOUR_DB_NAME");
Query query = dbRef
            .orderByChild("id")
            .equalTo("ID_OF_THE_USER");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d(TAG, dataSnapshot1.getKey() + "  " + dataSnapshot1.getValue(Profile.class)
                        .toString());
                updateUser(dataSnapshot1.getKey(),"ID_OF_THE_USER", "New_Name");
               }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

private void updateUser(DatabaseReference db,int key, String id, String name,) {
    User user = new User(id, name);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();
    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/data/" + key, postValues);
    db.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

Hope it will help you ....

Comment: Thanks. It really helped me.